# template with duck typing in C++

Tags: c++, templates, duck-typing

Is there a way to require a templates type to have properties?

For example:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void foo()
{
    U a,b;
    bool truthiness = T()(a,b);
    if (truthiness)
        // do something
}
```

So, how would I require that `T` have the `operator()(U a, U b)` defined, that returns a specific type?  Is this possible?  (I know it is in d, but I'm not sure about c++).

ps. if duck typing is wrong here, let me know, I believe it is correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to happen if it _doesn't_ have that operator? Syntax errors aside, you'll get a compiler error already -- what more do you want?

Comment: That's (part of) what `concept`s were supposed to provide -- a direct way to specify the requirements on the type(s) over which a template could be instantiated. Unfortunately, despite a lot of work, it didn't make it into the standard.

Comment: look up SFINAE, which is a technique designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: If what you want is the type `T` to implement `operator()(int,int)`, the syntax is wrong, as `operator()` must be applied to an instance of the type, not the type itself (i.e. `void foo( T& t ) { t(1,2); }`)

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Thanks!  That was exactly what I was interested in.  I also fixed the error, and made it more general.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong, considering your intent. Since `T` is a type, `T(1, 2)` would construct a temporary object of type `T` using a two-parameter constructor. If you wanted to call `T`s operator `()` you'd have to вo something like

```
T()(1, 2);
```

assuming a call through a temporary works for your purposes.

If `T` had no such operator `()`, the code would simply fail to compile. I'd actually say that one big benefit of template code is that it "works" as long as the syntax is valid (i.e. the very duck-typing you are talking about), i.e. there's no need to further restrict it by requiring the `operator ()` be present.

Of course, in my example it might actually make sense, since for `T = void (*)(int, int)` the code would be syntactically valid, but would result in a function call through a null pointer. But again, that's specific to my version of the code, and I don't know what specific object of type `T` you want to apply your operator `()` to.

Having said that, it is worth nothing that Boost library has quite a few features that allows one to check such properties and use them for branching in template meta-programming and/or in static assertions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into the boost library.  I have edited the question slightly, if you can answer the more general question.

Comment: @AndrewSpott: I am not sure if boost provides a solution, but [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/tree/browse_frm/thread/4f7c7a96f9afbe44/) provides a close solution.  Be aware that C++03 solutions will fail to compile if the `operator()` is private, as SFINAE cannot be used to detect accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

By simple expressing the template then you require for T to have `operator()(int, int)`. It will not compile if it doesn't.

However if you are creating an API and want to inform the user of the API that they have passed in an incompatible type then you need to create a type trait which detects the operator and you can specialise the function to discriminate on that fact and create a static_assert to indicate the fact.

Comment: This is where the game begins. The condition required for the template is *not* that an `operator()(int, int)` exists, the condition is that the expression `T(1,2)` is valid (actually should be `T()(1,2)` or similar, I think there's an error in the question). So for example, having `operator()(long, long)` is sufficient. You need to decide what you want to enforce, and why, but *normally* documenting in terms of the required expressions is the way to go, rather than in terms of the functions you think someone might implement to make those expressions valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to decltype, you can roll your own check relatively easily.

```
template <class T, class U> class check_same_type_t;

template <class T> class check_same_type_t<T, T> { };

template <class T, class U>
void foo()
{
    U a,b;
    check_same_type_t<bool, decltype(T()(a, b))> check;
    bool truthiness = T()(a,b);
    if (truthiness) ;
        // do something
}
```

Which enables the following:

```
struct A {
    bool operator()(int, int) { return true; }
};

struct B {
    int operator()(int, int) { return 1; }
};

int
main()
{
    foo<A, int>(); // will compile
    foo<B, int>(); // won't compile

}
```

Just make sure that this what you really want. **Forcing a generic algorithm to use a specific type may potentially come back to bite you.** If a type is implicitly convertible to bool, why is it unsatisfactory to use in your condition?